# Flow not detecting Firebase types

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, flowtype, flow-typed

I've installed `flow-typed` definitions for my project, but I am getting the following error in using some of the `Firebase` functionality.

```
const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ property `credential`. Property not found in
 45:           const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ statics of FacebookAuthProvider
```

How can I rectify this flow error?

Comment: can you try to log the "firebase" first and inspect what is inside ?

Comment: Maybe it's not initialized yet? Try `var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider(); const credential = provider.credential(token);`